# Sylius root taxonomy permalink

Tags: sylius

I'm working with latest release 0.15 and trying to make a simple url structure to work with single taxonomy (called category). How should one achieve the following link structure?

/a (list of taxons under the taxon a - a is not the root taxon)
/sub-a (list of products)

/b (again list of taxon under the taxon b)
/sub-b (list of products)

Currently the automatically created root taxon has fixed permalink which doesn't really fit in. So to narrow the question I could ask: **How to make root taxon's permalink empty?**

I bet that people encounter the same problem every time someone wants to suppress taxonomy's name from resulting url.

The rest could be solved with custom SlugHandler I guess or maybe with just a bit of gedmo sluggable configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The slug is generated by `Sylius\Bundle\TranslationBundle\GedmoHandler\TranslationSlugHandler`.

You can either override that class, or define a new `Handler` in the doctrine definition for the field.